# Filter return results printed in text file python

Tags: python, list, return, pprint

Using this code:

```
from pysnap import Snapchat
from pprint import pprint

s = Snapchat()

username = raw_input('Enter your username: ')
password = raw_input('Enter your password: ')
s.login(username, password)
friends = s.get_friends()

newfile = open("newfile.txt", "a")
pprint(friends, newfile)
```

It prints the return / results of get_friends()
Which is great, almost exactly what I want.

But.

The results are like this:

```
{u'can_see_custom_stories': True,
  u'direction': u'OUTGOING',
  u'display': u'',
  u'name': u'a7twini', #a7twini being the username here
  u'type': 0},
```

The ONLY thing I want it to display is:

```
a7twini
<nextusername>
<nextusername>
etc..
```

Is there a way to "filter" these results?
Making sure only the name ends up in the text file?

I hope someone can help me, thanks!

Edit: someone asked for the get_friends() function

```
def get_friends(self):
    """Get friends
    Returns a list of friends.
    """
    return self.get_updates().get('friends', [])
```

Comment: can you show `get_friends()` function ?

Comment: can you `print` the `friends` in your code and show it too ? thanks

Comment: If I just print it, it comes out as a string, I do not want that. Usernames need to be separated with a newline

Comment: DanielGibbs answer worked! Thanks for helping though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just print the `name` entry for each friend. Assuming `friends` is a list:

```
for friend in friends:
    newfile.write(friend[u'name'] + "\n")
```

Or you could use list comprehension:

```
newfile.writelines([friend[u'name'] + "\n" for friend in friends])
```

Comment: friends is a function

Comment: Not in your question it isn't: `get_friends` is a function and `friends` is where you store the results.

Comment: I see, can you explain what the for "friend" in friends: does?

Comment: For each element in the list `friends` it stores it in the local variable `friend`. It then writes the name of that friend to file. Read more about for loops at https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop.

Comment: If the answer helped would you mind marking it as accepted by clicking the tick mark next to it?

Comment: Had to wait a few mins before I was able to do that, just did. Thanks again!